# Volumetric Brush with opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry, volume

I have a cube and some points inside it. I'd like to create a volume from that points. Like a volumetric brush where each point is a brush stroke of a volumetric brush

After some research I've found that I can achieve this result with the so called isosurface. I've found a super neat example done with Java and Processing.org environment inside the [toxic libs](http://toxiclibs.org/), [here](https://code.google.com/p/toxiclibs/source/browse/trunk/toxiclibs/examples/volume/VolumeBrush/VolumeBrush.pde?r=210) you can see the example, VolumeBrush, for instance.

I don't need complicated or fast-and-optimized magic, I just need to make some volumes from some points, and intersect them.

What library in C++ for opengl are there? I will favour the simpler and easy-to-get-work solution!

Answer (score 0):

Check out Voreen. It's a general volume rendering software that uses OpenGL
http://www.voreen.org/